# how do you have a .py file execute in notepad?

Tags: python

so what I'm asking to be more specific is that when the .py file is opened it runs on notepad; so if I were to send the file to someone that doesn't have any kind of python compiler it would open in notepad.

Comment: yes, it would...

Comment: Yes, it would open in any text editor

Comment: It's just a text file dude, the magic happens in the python interpreter

Comment: You will be able to open the file, but running it to see the output, you will definitely need python installed on the receivers machine!

Comment: You will need notepad++ atleast to do the job.

Comment: _when the .py file is opened it runs on notepad_ That can't be true...

Comment: You need a python interpreter to open .py files

Comment: @scharette i think he means "runs" as in "is opened by"

Comment: @SuperStew but he says opened it runs

Comment: @TrooperZ yea i'm not sure, i think he is confused

Comment: @SuperStew Not to mention his question title is _how do you have a .py file execute in notepad?_ I think taking things for granted is not good practice here. We should instead flag the question and ask him for more feedback, because as it stands now the question is clearly too broad to properly answer it.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to open the `.py` file with any kind of text editor (including notepad), whether or not you have python installed.

The `.py` is just a text file storing your python code, reading/editing it has nothing to do with whether or not you have python installed.

Of course, you will not be able to actually ***run*** the code without python installed, only read/edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Any text editor will open files with `.py` extension irrespective of python interpreter installed or not. You would need a python interpreter installed to be able to **run** it.